# Why this OCaml syntax error

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml

I have this code in Ocaml

```
let double x = 2 * x

let triple x = 3 * x

let s = "Hello" in print_endline s

let () = triple 10 |> string_of_int |> print_endline
```

and when compiling with `ocamlc file.ml` this gives the error:

```
File "file.ml", line 5, characters 16-18:
Error: Syntax error
```

If I put `;;` at the end of line 3 like this

```
let triple x = 3 * x;;
```

of if I comment characters 16-18 in line 5 like this

```
let s = "Hello" (* in print_endline s *)
```

the syntax error goes away.

Can someone explain the reason of the syntax error, and what each of these two corrections do to resolve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`let s = "Hello" in print_endline s` is not a top level declaration even if it starts with `let`, it's a `let .. in` expression. If you don't terminate the preceding expression with `;;` it expects what comes next to be part of that expression instead of interpreting it as a top level declaration.

If you remove the `in ...` part you're changing it from a `let ... in` expression to a top level `let` declaration.

You can also turn it into a top level declaration like this:

```
let () = let s = "Hello" in print_endline s
```

Edit:

One way of thinking about this is, if instead of having

```
let triple x = 3 * x

let s = "Hello" in print_endline s
```

you replace `let s = ... in ...` with a simpler expression like just `"Hello"`:

```
let triple x = 3 * x

"Hello"
```

This is equivalent to

```
let triple x = 3 * x "Hello"
```

which will be parsed as applying the argument `"Hello"` to the function `x`

Comment: What you are saying is that the `let tripple ...` is an expression that needs to be terminated with `;;` to be a top-level declaration? If that is so, why does `let double ...` does not need the `;;` terminator to be considered top-level?

Comment: Sorry, i think I confused that a bit. `let tripple = ...` is not an expression, but what comes after the `=` is. So if `let s ...` can't unambiguously be niterpreted as a top level declaration, it's parsed as if it is part of the preceding expression. It might be simpler if you subtitute `let s ...` for a simpelr expression like just `"hello"`, where that would be parsed as applying an argument to the function `x`.

Comment: This is all a bit messy since eliding the `;;` terminators were a bit of an afterhtought I think, but the rule of thumb is: if what follows a top level declaration is not itself a top level declaration, you need to separate them with `;;`.

Comment: Alternatively you could turn `let s = ...` into a top level declaration: `let () = let s = "Hello" in print_endline s`

Comment: I like these two rules: 1) `"if what follows a top level declaration is not itself a top level declaration, you need to separate them with ;;"` and 2)  `"if let s ... can't unambiguously be interpreted as a top level declaration, it's parsed as if it is part of the preceding expression"`. I will remember both, and see how it goes. Thanks.